# What is Django model field choices best practices?

Tags: django

In my project I have  different apps and in models I have specific choices options separate for each `model.py`.

Like:

```
size = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                          choices=SIZE_CHOICES)

SIZE_CHOICES = (
    ('f','feet'),
    ('i','inches'),
    ('y','yards'),
    ('m','milimeters'),
    ('c','centimeters'),

)
```

However some of same choices options are shared between all the apps.

What is the best practise to have all the same  choices in single place? 
(Ideally somewhere where end user would be able to define them and not in the code.)

Comment: You can always define that in settings file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is create a specific app for that. So a `tools` app, for instance, in which I either define a `choices.py`, in which I hardcode the choices and then import them whereever I need them. 
Alternatively, you can create a simple model, in which you can create them yourself. Then you can use `__init__` functions to append them to a specific field. However, that solution will be overly complicated though, since you need to append those on runtime. 
The easiest solution is to just create a hardcoded `choices.py`. I've tried what you are trying to do once, and it turned out to be a huge mess. So unless you REALLY need it, I would advise to just manually manage a `choices.py` file.